# Keep Parent URL when navigating within iframe

Tags: javascript, php

On my iframe I can get the parent URL the first time it shows up, however when I start navigating within it, returns the iframe URL and I need to keep parent URL.

I use this code just to monitor the action on iframe

```
$site = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])['host'];
echo $site;
```

How to keep the parent URL when navigating within iframe?
Can be any language, I just want a code to keep parent URL information whatever iframe page I am.

Comment: You an save referer url into database or in session.